# Accessing QGIS attribute table description details

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kmz

I have opened a set of .kmz files in QGIS. When I inspect attributes related to specific details from the map space I can see the metadata is there (material, date, diameter etc...). However, when I open the attribute the table I get a HTML like object for the description, it shows the needed details in a popup-like object. Is there a way to expand this element such that the details within the description/popup are included in the attribute table properly? I know there are online conversion utilities that will take the .kmz and return the .shp with the details in the format I am asking about, but does QGIS have the ability to do this?

[image: QGIS metadata description in attribute table]

Comment: Provding sample data for testing would be helpful.

Comment: @Babel I found that KML Tools has the plugin I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else that comes across this question, the solution I found was to use the **KML Tools** plugin. There's a feature called 'Expand HTML description Field' and it does exactly what I was trying to do. It takes the HTML wrapped information in the 'description' column in the Attribute table and expands it into newly auto-named columns within the Attribute Table.